# Detect which program is blocked by firewall

Tags: linux, process, iptables, logs

The linux firewall can show a lot of information in the `LOG` target, for example via `--log-uid`.

How can the executable doing the network call be logged, too?

I did not find anything in the [FAQ](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq.html), the Iptables Tutorial 1.2.2, the manpages of `iptables` and `iptables-extensions`.

Comment: I don't think I have understood well the question, but maybee `netstat -tulpan` can help you. OT: I always remember that command params because I speak italian and the flower tulip is called "tulipano" XD

Comment: @lese: Mille Grazie, thank you. The question was originally on how to write the program name into the logs, but the comment is a nice workaround. (and the "tulipano" is a really nice mnemonic :-D)